# Align bars in ciplot

Tags: plot, stata

I'm working with the `ciplot` graphing module for Stata and am encountering a problem with the alignment of bars when I use the `by()` option. Here's a trivial example demonstrating the issue:

```
webuse citytemp, clear
ciplot heatdd cooldd, by(region) horizontal recast(conn)
```

[image: ciplot]

So, the graph shows means and confidence intervals for two variables across categories of the `region` variable. The bars for the different variables do not align horizontally, though. For each region, the point and bar for `heatdd` is one line above, and the point and bar for `cooldd` is one line below, the category label. I would like these to be on the same line, but I can't figure out how to achieve it.

I'm open to solutions that do not involve `ciplot`, but I have found it to be useful for the specific task I'm working on.

Comment: Because you have two variables,  if they were on the same line,  they could bump into each other.  In your example,  this would happen for **South**. Is this intended?

Comment: What advantage do you see in connecting the means with lines? I find it more difficult to interpret the graph as you're connecting different categories, not time points.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer Thanks. In my real data, they are time points, not categories but I wanted to provide a simple reproducible example here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my program (in Stata terms, downloadable via `ssc install ciplot`) so I can speak confidently. (On Statalist, it's expected that you explain the exact provenance of user-written programs; that would be good practice here too.)

It's not a bug; it's a feature (supposedly).

The offsets are entirely deliberate, to avoid messes when two or more intervals would just overlap and occlude each other, which is entirely likely when groups or comparable variables have similar values, which in turn is common when you do this. Even in your example, intervals for heating and cooling degree-days for the South would overlap otherwise, so the graph makes the point for me.

I can see that it's not what you want, but

1. There is no option in `ciplot` to remove the offset. I can see a case for one, **but**
2. My advice is now to use `statsby` to get a reduced dataset containing the confidence interval information, and then the graphics are typically a couple of command lines and you get to choose what you want. This approach is documented in a paper easily accessible [from the *Stata Journal*](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=gr0045).

You are always welcome to clone the program and modify the code using a different program name, with notional mention of the original.

Comment: Thanks, Nick! I was hoping you'd see this since I knew it was your program. That answers my question.

Comment: And in case anyone else comes across this, I've posted a modified ado file here: https://github.com/leeper/ciplotm

Comment: That's fine, but note that inside the help the references to `ciplot` should all to be `ciplotm`. Also, you are now first author: in determining order of authors, fraction of code written is less important than naming the person who should be approached for support.